# htmlTableRow not in designer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm now responsible for an ASP.net VB web forms application that I need to make a change to. I don't have much experience with asp.net so if I don't have this process right please let me know. I'm trying to hide two table rows depending on user permissions inside a nested table inside a repeater -- but the IDs of the TR don't appear in the designer and if I add it manually they don't stay long before VS removes it. In code behind, I'm getting `is not declared` errors for both IDs

```
<table>
    <asp:repeater ID="history" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="historyDetails">
        <itemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <%-- 
                        I'm trying to hide these 2 rows conditionally
                        without using <% if isAdmin then %> <% end if %> 
                        --%>
                        <tr id = "adminHeading" runat="server">
                            <td>...</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id = "adminNav" runat="server">
                            <td>...</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>...</tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </itemTemplate>
    </asp:repeater>
</table>
```

code behind

```
Protected Sub historyDetails(ByVal sender As Object)
    ...
    ...
    If session("isAdmin") Then
        adminHeading.visible = True 'produces not declared error
        adminNav.visible = True 'produces not declared error
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Check in the page declaration this: <%@ Page Language="VB" CodeFile="Page.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="Page" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

Comment: @ThanosMarkou Thanks for the reply, my page declaration is `<%@ Page Language="vb" EnableViewState="true"  ViewStateMode="disabled" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="myNeatFile.aspx.vb" Inherits="apps.myNeatFile" MasterPageFile="~/apps/apps.Master"%>`

Comment: Is the CodeBehind="myNeatFile.aspx.vb"  the correct one?

Comment: @ThanosMarkou yes. I have other elements that I populate via the codebehind and they work fine. Outside the repeater I've tried `<table id = "foo" runat="server"><tr id = "bar" runat="server">...` and they also show up in the designer as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not able to access `adminHeading` & `adminNav` in your code behind is because they are not direct present in your form tag directly rather they are present inside the repeater control. You can do this with ItemDataBound event by finding these table rows like this:-

```
Protected Sub historyDetails(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
   If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or _
       e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Then
         Dim adminHeading As HtmlTableRow = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("adminHeading"), _
                                                    HtmlTableRow)
         Dim adminNavAs HtmlTableRow = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("adminNav"), _
                                                    HtmlTableRow)
     'Check your condition and hide the rows
     If session("isAdmin") Then
         adminHeading.Visible = False
         adminNavAs.Visible = False
     End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) thank you for explaining WHY, and 2) thank you for showing an example. This works! You're my hero for the day.